# Interpolated string in database

Tags: c#, .net

Following interpolated string formation works well:

```
string BG="7263-2323";
string PG="2983-2323";

string interpolatedString = $"{BG};{PG}";
Console.WriteLine(interpolatedString);
```

Result in variable interpolatedString:

```
7263-2323;2983-2323
```

But, the problem is that I store interpolatedString in database, then it does not display values for BG and PG... Instead it displays string as it is:

```
$\"{BG};{PG}\"
```

How can I solve this issue? Any idea?

Comment: How do you store them, show the code where you insert the data. Also, why do you store multiple things in the same colunm at all? Why do you even store the literal string at all? You only need the `BG` and the `PG` values.

Comment: String interpolation is a compiler feature. After compilation the application knows nothing about variables or anything. You can do things with numbered placeholders since you know the variables beforehand.

Comment: You need to write your own interpolated strings parser to fill in properties/variables at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Interpolated strings are effectively just syntactic sugar for using [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead you would need to store your strings like this:

```
Hello {0}, welcome to my app
```

And then use `string.Format`:

```
var format = "Hello {0}, welcome to my app";
var output = string.format(format, "Bob");
```

Alternatively you could roll your own, for example:

```
var format = "Hello {name}, welcome to my app";
var output = format.Replace("{name}", "Bob");
```

Note that my example here isn't particularly efficient so you may want to use something like [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're doing a lot of this.